# scrollIntoView() angular 7 not scrolling

Tags: angular, typescript, js-scrollintoview

I am trying to implement scrolling from one component to another in my application, but at the moment it is only "jumping" to the component, and not scrolling.

I have tried the following:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
      el.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start',  behavior: 'smooth', inline: 'nearest' });
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Here is my template:

```
<section class="bg-full bg-home">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <a (click)="scroll(testPortfolio)" href="#portfolio" id="scroll-to-section">
    <img src="../../assets/arrow-scroll.svg" width="36">
  </a>
</section>
<app-about></app-about>
<app-portfolio-slider #testPortfolio></app-portfolio-slider>
<app-contact></app-contact>
```

Alternatively, I have also tried with the use of `ViewChild()`, but this always returns `undefined` as I assume it because `<app-portfolio-slider>` is not rendered yet.

What do I need to do in order for the scrolling to happen smoothly?

Comment: I would suggest you wrap your target component inside an HTML tag which will give you an HTML element which has got the `scrollIntoView`  method on it. The below snippet should work
`<div  #testPortfolio>
<app-portfolio-slider></app-portfolio-slider>
</div>`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrd1ua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my assumption was incorrect. As **@arbghl** mentioned in comments author just needed to wrap target element with `<div>` which has `scrollIntoView()` method and use that div as a target element.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you.  To make your solution work, I needed to wrap my <app-portfolio-slider> in a <div> tag.